# Why does pandas DataFrame's [] (__getitem__) sometimes select columns, sometimes rows?

Tags: python, pandas

Given this data frame:

```
In [40]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1], 'B': [2, 2], 'C': [3, 3]})

In [41]: df
Out[41]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
```

If I pass a list of strings to `[]`, it will filter columns:

```
In [42]: df[['A', 'C']]
Out[42]:
   A  C
0  1  3
1  1  3
```

But if I pass a list of booleans to `[]`, it will filter rows:

```
In [45]: df[[True, False]]
Out[45]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
```

Is there a way to think about this difference, rather than "it's just the way it is"?

Comment: Yes, the crux of it is that `df[...]` generally tries to apply whatever you pass to `__getitem__` as column indexers, except for the case where you pass a boolean mask. For example, try `df[[0, 1]]` and you'll see.

Comment: Isn't this quite unintuitive? I would think that the boolean mask will still select columns. It seems like the best practice is to always use `.loc` which explicitly has both row index and column index.

Comment: Indeed that is the best practice, but it helps shave a few characters if you know what you're doing ;)

Comment: The [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data) actually recommends to use the `.loc` method (or `.iloc` method) in production code (also for optimization reasons). The `[]` index operator is basically a 'convenience' method: it's designed to let you access data values with the least amount of characters for some of the most common use cases.

Comment: Most of time , I will using .loc instead of [].

Comment: @Wen In my experience `iloc` is often what you look for, e.g. `df.iloc[[True,False],[True,False,True]]` which would do both operations mentioned here.

Comment: But loc would give you the chance to use `df.loc[[True,False],['A','C']]`. Yeah, I'm divided. @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, any comment on this?

Comment: @AntonvBR I don't believe you can use boolean masks with `iloc`, in which case you must use the other :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You meant the other way around right? With iloc we are restricted to use boolean masks for row and columns where as loc opens up using column names.

Comment: @AntonvBR What!! I used to get NotImplementedErrors doing this before... ^^;

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that this copied R's behavior to make migrating R scripts easier, it also started with `ix` to which is deprecated. There was a *lot* of ways to to do slicing, but we have fewer now:

1. single item, get a column.
2. list of columns, get a "subframe"
3. boolean indexing

Personally I like to use `__getitem__` for all of those:

```
In [11]: df[['A', 'C']]
Out[11]:
   A  C
0  1  3
1  1  3

In [12]: df['A']
Out[12]:
0    1
1    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

The alternative, though it has less ambiguity (`loc` (or `iloc`) is too verbose:

```
In [13]: df.loc[:, ['A', 'B']]
Out[13]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  2

In [14]: df.loc[:, 'A']
Out[14]:
0    1
1    1
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

It's worth noting that boolean masking is *not* ambiguous, unless you have an esoteric example where the boolean columns and the input length matches that of the DataFrame:

```
In [21]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({True: [1, 2], False: [3, 4]})

In [22]: df1
Out[22]:
   False  True
0      3      1
1      4      2

In [23]: df1[[True, False]]  # boolean slicing (not as column names)
Out[23]:
   False  True
0      3      1
```

Historically, there was potential ambiguity in `ix` (as well as performance issues - there's a lot of possible paths to take). So as well as removing ambiguity, the move to `loc` and `iloc` also led to faster code (generally use `iloc` if you can it's the fastest).

Comment: R does not have this ambiguity regarding `[]`, which is why I was confused. `df[...]` always filters columns in R, for example `df[c('A', 'C')]` and `df[c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)]` both keep columns `A` and `C`.

Comment: @Heisenberg in R I thought it would be `df[, c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)]` ? Logical indexing is that same as in pandas I thought... https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/modules/subsetting-data/

Comment: In R, like you said we can do `df[row_index, col_index]` to subset. We can *also* do `df[col_index]` to select columns, with `col_index` being either labels, integer, or boolean. `df[col_index]` always select columns in R, which is what I meant by saying "R does not have this ambiguity regarding `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

The [Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) documentation mentions that the `[]` operator is provided more for convenience. So whether it works on rows or columns seems to be based on what is considered as common operation.

> The Python and NumPy indexing operators `[]` and attribute operator `.` provide quick and easy access to pandas data structures across a wide range of use cases. This makes interactive work intuitive, as there’s little new to learn if you already know how to deal with Python dictionaries and NumPy arrays. However, since the type of the data to be accessed isn’t known in advance, directly using standard operators has some optimization limits. For production code, we recommended that you take advantage of the optimized pandas data access methods exposed in this chapter.

> With DataFrame, slicing inside of `[]` slices the rows. This is provided largely as a convenience since it is such a common operation.

> You may select rows from a DataFrame using a boolean vector the same length as the DataFrame’s index.

> Since indexing with `[]` must handle a lot of cases (single-label access, slicing, boolean indexing, etc.), it has a bit of overhead in order to figure out what you’re asking for.

So far what I've found is:

**Select rows**

- Boolean indexing `df[[True, False]]`
- Slicing `df[0:1]`

**Select columns**

- Single label `df['A']`
- List of labels `df[['A', 'C']]`

Though they have picked behaviors that seem reasonable, "it is just the way it is". Also, there seems to be no clear documentation for the `[]` index operator - at least that would have been helpful.